# Finding the size of a finite reflection group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was trying to deduce the statistical dimension of the equispace-designed convex cone using the ideas of finite reflection and Coxeter groups. The original problem is immaterial in this discussion, so let me straightaway go to the point. My basic problem is as follows:

I have a set of reflections in the $n$-dimensional Eucidean space, which are reflections about the hyperplanes:
$$
\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : (0,0,...,0,1,-2,1,0,...,0,0) \cdot x = 0\}
$$
(there are $n-2$ such reflections). My targets are:

> ($1$)  To calculate the cardinality of the finite reflection group generated by these reflections. Is there any easy way to do this?
>
> ($2$)  To calculate the number of maps in this f.r.g. with $1$-eigendimension = $d$, for $d$ between $1$ and $n$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on how to typeset math on this site.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group generated by these reflections is not finite.

In particular, the angle between the hyperplanes
$$
(1,-2,1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)\cdot \textbf{x}=0
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
(0,0,1,-2,1,0,0,\ldots)\cdot\textbf{x} = 0
$$
is $\cos^{-1}(1/6)$, which is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.